# Recursive Add on a List<T> containing List<T> Elements

Tags: c#, list, recursion, tree

I'm trying to refactor some code using recursion to extend the possibility (and clean up the code).

Here is the problem:

I have a Treeview object that looks like a folder structure:

```
- ElementA
- ElementB
   - Element B1
   - Element B2
      - Element B2-1
   - Element B3
      - Element B3-1
         - Element B3-1-1
- Element C
```

```
This is the guilty class:

public class TreeNode
{
        private readonly string name;   //Name of the node
        private readonly string path;   //Path of the node \\foo\\foo\\bar
        public List<TreeNode> children; //list of TreeNode children

        public void Add(TreeNode tName) //Add a child to a specific node
        {
            if (this.children is null)
                this.children = new List<TreeNode>();
            this.children.Add(tName);
        }
}
```

I have to create a TreeNode list based on a list of the folders I'm getting from a backend.

Now my code:

```
List<TreeNode> nList = new List<TreeNode>();   // The list I want to fill in
ICollection<CfgFolder> folders= new List<CfgFolder>();  //Collection of folder to base myself on

//here get CfgFolder list from backend
//...
//

foreach (var folder in folders)
{
    TreeNode newRow = new TreeNode(folder.Name, folder.ObjectPath); //Create a TreeNode without children (this is the new object to add)
    bool added = false;
    if (nList.Count == 0) // Add first element
        nList.Add(new TreeNode(folder.Name, folder.ObjectPath));
    else
    {   
        foreach (var child in nList.ToList())
        {
            if (child.Path == newRow.Path) // If first level add simply to the list (same initial path \\Root )
            {
                nList.Add(new TreeNode(folder.Name, folder.ObjectPath));
                added = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!added)
        {
            foreach (var child in nList.ToList())
            {
                if (child.Path + "\\" + child.Name == newRow.Path) // If second level add to a child (path like \\ROOT\\Folder )
                {
                    nList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == child.Name).Add(new TreeNode(folder.Name, folder.ObjectPath));
                    added = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (!added)
        {
            foreach (var child in nList.ToList())
            {
                foreach (var child2 in child.children)
                {
                    if (child2.Path + "\\" + child2.Name == newRow.Path) // If third level add to a child of the child (path like \\ROOT\\Folder\\SubFolder )
                    {
                        nList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == child.Name).children.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == child2.Name).Add(new TreeNode(folder.Name, folder.ObjectPath));
                        added = true;
                        break;
                    }

                }

            }
        }
        //Also 4th level, ... till n level
    }
}
```

This is working fine, I can obtain the wanted structure but this is not good looking and I'm struggling on creating Recursive method that return my `nList` updated correctly.

This looks like this but as I'm rewriting "Mylist" on each recursive call, this is not good :-(

Anyway, I'm able to find the correct place to add the folder but not to update the initial `nList` correctly.

```
private List<TreeNode> Recursive(List<TreeNode> Mylist, TreeNode newRow, bool added, int? loop = 0)
{
   if (!added)
   {
      foreach (var child in Mylist.ToList())
      {
         if (child.Path + "\\" + child.Name == newRow.Path) 
         {
            Mylist.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == child.Name).Add(new TreeNode(newRow.Name, newRow.ObjectPath)); //This line is false it should be something like nList[Mylist.Position]
            added = true;
            break;
          }

       }
   }
   if (added)
      return Mylist; //This line is false also
   return Recursive(Mylist[loop??0].children.ToList(), newRow, added, path,loop+1);
}
```

I hope my explanation is understandable enough.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a more generic tree having a generic key and generic value type. The idea is to create a reusable collection like `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`. The class `Tree<TKey, TValue>` is the root of recursive structure and the base class of `TreeNode<TKey, TValue>`. This makes every node a tree as well, which is fine since every node can be the root of a sub-tree.

```cs
public class Tree<TKey, TValue>
{
    public List<TreeNode<TKey, TValue>> Children { get; } = new();

    public void Add(TKey[] keys, TValue value)
    {
        ...
    }
}

public class TreeNode<TKey, TValue> : Tree<TKey, TValue>
{
    public TreeNode(TKey key)
    {
        Key = key;
    }

    public TKey Key { get; }
    public TValue Value { get; set; }
}
```

The `Tree<,>` has only a `Children` property. `TreeNodes<,>` adds `Key` and `Value` properties.

If we want to add an element at a deeper level, we need all the keys specifying a path trough the tree structure. Therefore, the `keys` parameter of `Add` is an array of keys. For your specific problem, the key would be the name of a folder (without the path). The value could be anything, like the full path or a [DirectoryInfo Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo?view=net-5.0) or [FileInfo Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo?view=net-5.0) or their common ancestor `FileSystemInfo` to be able to mix directory and file info.

Let us implement the public `Add` method. It calls a private recursive `Add` method having an extra `index` parameter referring to the key in the array used at the current recursion level.

```cs
public void Add(TKey[] keys, TValue value)
{
    Add(keys, value, 0);
}

private void Add(TKey[] keys, TValue value, int index)
{
    TKey key = keys[index];
    TreeNode<TKey, TValue> child = Children.FirstOrDefault(c => Equals(c.Key, key));
    if (child is null) {
        child = new TreeNode<TKey, TValue>(key);
        Children.Add(child);
    }
    if (index == keys.Length - 1) {
        child.Value = value;
    } else {
        child.Add(keys, value, index + 1);
    }
}
```

Let us add a print method to the `Tree<,>` for testing:

```cs
public void PrintChildren()
{
    foreach (var child in Children) {
        child.Print("");
    }
}
```

It calls a recursive print method declared in `TreeNode<,>`:

```cs
public void Print(string indent = "")
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{indent}- {Key} = {Value}");
    foreach (var child in Children) {
        child.Print(indent + "   ");
    }
}
```

We can test it with:

```cs
var tree = new Tree<string, string>();
var folders = new List<string> {
    @"Element A",
    @"Element B\Element B1",
    @"Element B\Element B2\Element B2-1",
    @"Element B\Element B3",
    @"Element B\Element B3\Element B3-1",
    @"Element B\Element B3\Element B3-1\Element B3-1-1",
    @"Element C"
};

foreach (string folder in folders) {
    string[] keys = folder.Split('\\');
    tree.Add(keys, folder);
}

tree.PrintChildren();
```

You will see that we insert the values only as leaves. If we wanted to have values at every level, we would have to add the B2 folders as

```
@"Element B",
@"Element B\Element B2",
@"Element B\Element B2\Element B2-1",
```

Comment: Hello Olivier!
Thanks for really quick answer.
I have tested it and the way it works is interesting :-)
Unfortunately, I can't change the structure of the current TreeNode class :-(

Comment: But you can apply the same algorithm to your existing TreeNode class. Just replace `Key` by `name` and `Value` by `path`.

Comment: I have refactored my solution by splitting the `TreeNode` class into a `Tree` and a `TreeNode` class. This reflects the fact that the tree has children but no key or value.

Comment: I have smally adapted your solution by using the idea of splitting the path and this is working perfectly :-)
Many thanks for the help!